# Liftweb "Sign Up" menu item

Tags: xml, scala, xhtml, lift

Does anyone happen to know what the name is used for the sign up menu item?  I've tried `<lift:menu.item name="Signup"  name="sign.up"  name="sign_up"`  all to no avail.  `name="Login"` produces a Log In link just fine.

What am I actually doing wrong here?

Comment: You're gonna need to provide more details - your question is very, very unclear.

Comment: Ok say I want to make a link to a registration view.  When you first start up a liftweb application Menu.Builder gives you Static Content, login sign up etc. 

Now ANYWHERE on my page I can put <lift:menu.item name="Login"/> and it produces a Log In link.  I was just wondering what name is used for SignUp  because <lift:menu.item name="sign.up"/> doesn't work, nor does "SignUp" or Sign_up"

Comment: Like I throw this in my html file 
<lift:menu.item name="Login">Log In</lift:menu.item> 
   <lift:menu.item name="Sign_up">Sign Up</lift:menu.item>
   and I do get a Login link.  however it acts as if Sign Up doesn't even exist.  I was just wondering if it does some sort of matching off of the name attribute.  That's the only reason why I can see that would cause it to simply not show up.

Comment: Please, edit your _question_ with clarification. Do not post it as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `name="CreateUser"`.

The definition is like this (somewhere in ProtoUser.scala in Lift 2.1):

```
/** 
 * The menu item for creating the user/sign up (make this "Empty" to disable) 
 */  
def createUserMenuLoc: Box[Menu] =  
  Full(Menu(Loc("CreateUser", signUpPath, S.??("sign.up"), createUserMenuLocParams)))
```

Comment: Sweet!  100% what i needed and thanks for telling me where to look.  I really need to start reading through the sourcecode for lift.  *pulling now*